# Create new file with GTK

Tags: c, file, gtk

I have function creating a text file, I want that the user can choose the name and path of this text file opening a browse window. I saw gtkfilechooser but user only can choose a file and note create one defining name of the file.

I hope to have been clear.

Comment: *I hope to have been clear..*: exactly the opposite.

Comment: Sorry english is not my mother tongue, just as a "Save as.." option I want user can chose path and filename in a window like gtkfilechooser

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to make an entry for filename and only use gtkfilechooser to chose path of the file but I think there is better way.

Comment: Post the code and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

GtkFileChooser and its implementations (GtkFileChooserButton, GtkFileChooseDialog, and GtkFileChooserWidget) can run in four modes: open file, save file, open folder, create folder. You want the save file mode. Look up [GtkFileChooserAction](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkFileChooser.html#GtkFileChooserAction) and [`gtk_file_chooser_set_action()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-action). Note that if you use GtkFileChooserDialog, this is one of the parameters to `gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new()`.